# PHP storing array in database

Tags: php, arrays

I have saved a array inn my database using `var_export($myarray, true)`.

But when I'm trying to get the array from the database later I can't figure out how to do it. Here is what I've tried now

```
$henl = $yam->fetchObject(User::class);
$bfore = $henl->bfore;
echo $bfore["obj2"];
```

This does not work, but when I echo `$henl->bfore` I get this:

```
array (
  'obj1' => 1000000000,
  'obj2' => 0,
  'obj3' => 100,
  'obj4' => 9032,
  'obj4' => 0,
)
```

So my question is how do I get `$bfore["obj2"]` to print out the value of obj2 in the array?

Here is how it looks in the database:

[image]

Comment: What is in the database? Can you do a SELECT?

Comment: You can't do it because you're trying to use the _string_ `array(...)` as an _array_...

Comment: @Steven is it another way to do this?

Comment: You''d need to use `exec` to run the code created by `var_export`. I recommend against this method, I'm sure there's a better way (perhaps store the array as json instead)

Comment: @user2182349 im trying to use the array that ive stored in "bfore".
Im getting this array whit $henl->bfore; and this is the content of "bfore" in the database:
array (
  'obj1' => 1000000000,
  'obj2' => 0,
  'obj3' => 100,
  'obj4' => 9032,
  'obj4' => 0,
)

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Snk6Pb9.png here is a picture that shows how it looks in the database

Comment: yes `var_export` creates a php-parsable string, but its not intended to use for serialization/deserialization. Use `serialize`/`unserialize` or `json_encode`/`json_decode` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using `var_export`

**BE AWARE** This method is included because this is the answer to the question as asked; however, either of the other two methods is what you are actually looking for!

Let's assume you have an array...

```
$array = [
  'obj1' => 1000000000,
  'obj2' => 0,
  'obj3' => 100,
  'obj4' => 9032,
  'obj4' => 0,
];
```

You can turn it into a string like so (presumably this is what you do)...

```
$arrayString = var_export($array, true);

var_dump($arrayString);

/* Output:

string(80) "array (
  'obj1' => 1000000000,
  'obj2' => 0,
  'obj3' => 100,
  'obj4' => 0,
)"

*/
```

As you can see the `$arrayString` contains a string and not an array. You need to `eval` the string to return it to a usable array...

```
eval('$returnedArray = ' . $arrayString . ';');

var_dump($returnedArray);

/* Output:

array(4) {
  ["obj1"]=>
  int(1000000000)
  ["obj2"]=>
  int(0)
  ["obj3"]=>
  int(100)
  ["obj4"]=>
  int(0)
}

*/

echo $returnedArray["obj2"];

// Output: 0
```

### Using `json_*`

Of course there are many potential pitfalls using `eval` in your code (especially if you don't have full control/supervision over the *strings* that will be passed to it!

So a better option may be to encode the data in a JSON string. PHP has built in functions to do just this: `json_encode` and `json_decode`

Convert array to JSON string:

```
$jsonString = json_encode($array);

var_dump($jsonString);

/* Output:
    
    string(48) "{"obj1":1000000000,"obj2":0,"obj3":100,"obj4":0}"

*/
```

Convert back to array:

```
$returnedArray = json_decode($jsonString, true); // The second parameter forces return of an array over an object

var_dump($returnedArray);

/* Output:

array(4) {
  ["obj1"]=>
  int(1000000000)
  ["obj2"]=>
  int(0)
  ["obj3"]=>
  int(100)
  ["obj4"]=>
  int(0)
}

*/
```

### Using `serialize`

Naturally it doesn't stop there. PHP has specific functions to *serialize* data so that it can be stored in a textual format and returned to PHP usable data as well...

Serialize the string:

```
$serialString = serialize($array);

var_dump($serialString);

/* Output:

string(77) "a:4:{s:4:"obj1";i:1000000000;s:4:"obj2";i:0;s:4:"obj3";i:100;s:4:"obj4";i:0;}"

*/
```

Return the serialized string to a variable:

```
$returnedArray = unserialize($serialString);

var_dump($returnedArray);

/* Output:

array(4) {
  ["obj1"]=>
  int(1000000000)
  ["obj2"]=>
  int(0)
  ["obj3"]=>
  int(100)
  ["obj4"]=>
  int(0)
}

*/
```